# AdMob won't load programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I'm need to include ads into my app and I have a settings option to disable ads. so I need to load the ad in code. I copied the code from google to handle that and when I set `ads:loadAdOnCreate` to `true`, it works just fine.

But if I set it to false and add the two lines

```
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

The ads stop displaying. If I look at log cat, it shows that it is receiving an ad and trying to display it. However it won't actually display on screen. Help?

No matter if I'm loading the ad in xml or in code, the following warning shows up in logcat despite the fact I'm giving the banner the whole screen.
`11-16 18:53:37.128: W/Ads(19401): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <456, 133>`

Comment: Have you tried doing a `setVisible` on your ad object?

Comment: I haven't, but it should be visible already, right?

Comment: I tried calling `adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` but I still have the issue of it not showing up.

Comment: Can you post the XML for your layout?  It doesn't think there is enough room to lay out the ad for some reason.

Comment: antew, You were right; as I state in my answer, android wasn't providing the view enough room, even though nothing was in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I was including a fragment whose height was set to `fill_parent`. I changed that setting to `wrap_content` and everything worked.